# Nested Loop number output

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I need to output this

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

So far all I have is:

```
def main():
    for i in range(10):
        for n in range(i):
            print(i)

    return
main()
```

I get all the correct numbers, it's just not formatted correctly. If you guys could throw some hints my way I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What output are you getting? That would help....

Comment: Since your problem seems to be getting rid of the newlines only, this question is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386

Comment: 1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
6
6
6
6
6
6
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9 This is my output right now, and I have to use a nested for loop for the assignment

Answer (score 13):

Simply multiply the string version:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(str(i) * i)
```

Output:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(str(i) * i)
... 

1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

If you *have* to use a nested loop, tell the `print()` function to not print a newline in the inner loop by setting the `end` option to an empty string; an empty `print()` call in the outer loop then suffices to add the necessary newline:

```
for i in range(10):
    for n in range(i):
        print(i, end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much every answer stated above uses string to accomplish this problem. There is another way, a more easier way by applying simple math using the formula a_n= n * ((10^n - 1)/9) for n<=9. Please refer the snippet below (Using Python 3)

```
for i in range(1,n)
    print i*(((pow(10,i)-1) // 9)
```

> n = 4

Output

```
1 
22
333
4444
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    for i in range(10):
        for n in range(i):
            print(i, end='')

        print()

main()
```

Comment: The fact it's that easy makes me sad, but I guess that's why I need practice

Comment: There's always a learning curve, don't worry. Pick a book you like, print it and take your time...

Comment: This prints *two* newlines after each number series.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right, I haven't noticed the exact spacing in the question. I edited out the '\n' argument in the last print statement.

Comment: The exact spacing was wrong in the original post; a classical error made when first encountering MarkDown and Stack Overflow, where an editor tries to come to grips with the way paragraphs are handled (you need a double newline or else text is flowed into paragraphs). In this case the solution was to use preformatted text instead by indenting.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main(n):
  for x in range(n):
    if x>0:
      print(str(x)*x+'\n')

main(n)
```

Comment: The OP is using the print *function*, not *statement*, so there should be parentheses.  OR, at least you might want to point out this answer is valid for python2, not python3.

Answer (score 0):

One line, and don't use str:

```
print((10**(i)//9)*i)
```